# Plot 3 selected random number of time-series data

Tags: python, plot, time-series

I have a time series data with 9 classes and would like to show 3 randomly selected time series of each class.

Code below plots all the data. My questions are:

1) What is the meaning of the part inside the brackets in this line (`for x in X[y == (i+1)]:`)?

2) How I can plot 3 times series of each class and not all the data?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
for i, classe in enumerate(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']):
    plt.subplot(9, 1, i + 1)
    plt.yscale('log')
    for x in X[y == (i+1)]:
        plt.plot(x, color='C0', linewidth=0.9)
    plt.title('Class: {}'.format(classe), fontsize=16)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)
plt.show()
```

snapshot of my data looks like this:

[image]

And this is how my plots look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1-about your first question i what in Y and X i your code?i think that part is for plotting a time series elements but since i dont know your data i cant answer clearly
2- about second part i suggest to generate 3 random numbers between 1,9 which they are your series and put this list in your plot, like here.

```
import random
rand1= random.randint(1, 9)
rand2= random.randint(1, 9)
rand3= random.randint(1, 9)
print(rand1,rand2,rand3)
#im not sure if this part is necesary but i wrote to be sure it follows your code pattern

rand1=str(rand1)
rand2=str(rand2)
rand3=str(rand3)
a=[rand1,rand3,rand2]
print(a)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
for i, classe in enumerate(a):
    plt.subplot(len(a), 1, i + 1)
    plt.yscale('log')
    for x in X[y == (i+1)]:
        plt.plot(x, color='C0', linewidth=0.9)
    plt.title('Class: {}'.format(classe), fontsize=16)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)
plt.show()
```

i dont have your data so i couldnt run the code to see the plot.if it gives any error let me know

Comment: Hi ssssoooo

I think my question is not clear. I have 9 classes of data and have more than 50 time series for each class. What I want to do is to plot all the classes but 3 time series for each class.

I will add a snapshot of my data to the question.